# How to create lookup field programmatically using AddFieldAsXml Method?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, addfieldasxml

i have two lists(Invoice & Client) which i had created dynamically through code and i want to create lookup field programmatically for relationship between this two list.
In Invoice List i have following columns:
1.ID
2.InvoiceNo
3.ClientId - this column i need to create as lookup 
4.ClientId:ClientName - this column is used to get ClientName from Client List when i enter ID in ClientId Column
5.etc

In Client List i have following columns:
1.ID
2.ClientName
3.Address
4.etc

So far i'm able to create lookfield that is ClientId in invoice list 3rd column but how can i create programmatically 4th column has additional column.

When we create lookup column using sharepoint administration there is an option called 
"Add a column to show each of these additional fields" this i want to create programmatically

**My Code**

```
 List refList= webobj.Lists.GetByTitle(Constants.Client);
 clientContext.Load(refList);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 Field LookUpField = listObj.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
 "<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='ClientId' Required='FALSE' List='" + refList.Id + "' 
 ShowField='ID' StaticName='ClientId' 
 Name='ClientId' />", true,AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
 LookUpField.Update();
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add ID to the lookup field you have already created. Suppose the ID is `1dbc2f2f-f7b7-4d38-aa60-5f23c737729e`. So your field xml will look like this:

```
<Field ID='{1dbc2f2f-f7b7-4d38-aa60-5f23c737729e}' Type='Lookup' DisplayName='ClientId' Required='FALSE' List='" + refList.Id + "' 
 ShowField='ID' StaticName='ClientId' 
 Name='ClientId' />
```

Now create another field with following XML:

```
<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='ClientId:ClientName' List='" + refList.Id + "'
  ShowField="ClientName" FieldRef='1dbc2f2f-f7b7-4d38-aa60-5f23c737729e'  
  ID='{86e03e0b-c124-41e0-be41-0e1f6f94bc15}' StaticName='ClientId_x003a_ClientName' 
  Name='ClientId_x003a_ClientName' />
```

Add this field to the filedcollection of the list. Notice that the ID of first field is referenced in second field using `FieldRef`

Comment: ID value can be any random number or any other sequence i should use thnks

Comment: ID can be anything as long as it satisfies the format. You can use visual studio to generate one. Go to Visual Studio and click on tools-> then create GUID