# Create lookup column in SharePoint Hosted Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm using this xml in order to declare a lookup column :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
 <Field
   ID="{2360b46a-f4b9-4cd5-b8a3-98eca46b0067}"
   Name="FromDuration"
   DisplayName="From Duration"
   Type="Lookup"
   ShowField="Title"
   List="Lists/DurationSettings"
   Overwrite="TRUE"
   Required="TRUE"
   Group="Leave Request App Group">
   </Field>
  </Elements>
```

Even though it is declared ok , i don't get any values in the lookup field.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your **DurationSettings** List contains list items ?

Comment: Yes it does . I have list items with Fields : Title (the default one) and Hours . So it has two fields. The list items are added through the SharePoint add-in hardcoded but i also tried to add some manually . The lookup fields won't read them. I think something is wrong with the mapping of the lookup field and the title field

Answer (score 1):

```
<Field ID="{8b26ec41-b6c3-4327-0066-0c18c0768626}" Name="InternalName" StaticName="InternalName" DisplayName="Display Name" Type="Lookup" ShowField="Title" Mult="TRUE" List="Lists/LookupList" Overwrite="TRUE" />
```

Useful links Check this once.

[Link 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119667/how-to-create-lookup-field-programmatically-using-addfieldasxml-method)

[Link 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86362/how-to-create-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-lists-within-sharepoint-apps)

Comment: May b this link will useful to create lookup column in SharePoint Apps using XML.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i still don't understand. I create Site Columns , i add them to the Site Content Types and then add the Content Type to the list. I added the column "From Duration" into the Contenty Type and then into the list. Do i need to write code to add this field? For standard fields all i do is create them and add them to Site Content type. Now i need to add the lookup field programmatically by using clientContext?

Comment: No need to write code. You just open default.xml file and add the lookup field.
Note the lookup to the list which is accomplished purely with declarative XML courtesy of the “List="Lists/DurationSettings"
[Check this link](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/08/create-lists-content-types-files-etc.html)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Are you sure this works? Have you tested it ? Don't know why it doesn't work. Its a simple lookup field

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to give priority to the feature which deploys the list that you want to lookup for (the source list). You can do that by changing the feature activation order in the Package manifest.